# A program to computer smallest number of notes that will combine to give Rs. N?

Tags: python-3.x

Consider a currency system in which there are notes of six denominations, namely, Rs. 1, Rs. 2, Rs. 5, Rs. 10, Rs. 50, Rs. 100.
If the sum of Rs. N is input, write a program to computer smallest number of notes that will combine to give Rs. N.

Output-

For each test case, display the smallest number of notes that will combine to give N, in a new line.

I tried this code-

[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAUE9.png)

Comment: Post your code as text not image, so others can easily copy it.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code to your post. A typo: you didn't define `t` before the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
curr = (100,50,10,5,1)

n = 576

count = 0
i = 0
rem = n

while rem!=0:
    count += rem//curr[i]
    rem = n % curr[i]
    i += 1

print(count)
```